# Indeed RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rabbitmq

I do not know why the processing of page does not stops when it dequeue. I am using Dot net/C#. How can I show the messages If this deadlock does not stops?

Moreover I have seen in tutorial to create a exchange and then create a dynamic queue and bind it in Tutorial no. 3. but how come in this code, I have taken it from rabbitMQ c# Examples but they have not used this.

I can not find the random created queue and then binding with exchange.
Emit Code is given over here::https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/dotnet/EmitLog.cs

and In receive, If we have not created any queue while emit/send log , then why we are creating that here ::
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/dotnet/ReceiveLogs.cs

and most of the all deadlock in this code where there is written Dequeue.

```
 using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                    {
                        channel.ExchangeDeclare("logs", "fanout");
                        var queueName = channel.QueueDeclare();
                        channel.QueueBind(queueName, "logs", "");
                        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                        channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
                        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for logs." +
                                          "To exit press CTRL+C");
                        while (true)
                        {
                            var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                            var body = ea.Body;
                            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                            Console.WriteLine(" [x] {0}", message);
                        }
                    }
```

1)One more question, I am using exchange to send the message to all users. IS it right or wrong? Because I am not getting anything after reading tutorials also.they are confusing.
I want to write a message in a text box then I want that whenever any user clicks on receive message, he/she should receive that message.Can this be possible using Exchanges?

2)And For everytime/everytime when page will open, I have to create a new Queue/Exchange?

Please Help me.